# Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon - Fn Keys Brightness Level Intervals

Tags: linux, linux-mint, brightness, fn-key

I have a question in regards to setting the brightness level on laptop display using the function keys; I have determined that my screen is capable of having it's brightness level set to values 1-10 using:

`pkexec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness [1-10]`

However when I use my function keys to change brightness, I can only set intervals 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10; I'd like to be able to set smaller intervals when adjusting my brightness and am wondering if there's any way to change what intervals the function keys use to change brightness?